# Restricting access to UK IPs without sacrificing Ubuntu's functionality

Tags: networking, apt, server, updates

I have a customer who restricts outbound traffic to anything outside of the US. Just came up today. I realized that `us.archive.ubuntu.com` actually points to an IP address that falls within Canonical's IP range that sits in the UK.

As a result, I assume the customer's not going to be install updates, etc. because of this. I feel like I have to be missing something because US was selected in the installation process, but this whole situation is relatively new for me so I'm a bit confused as to what to suggest, other than a different OS that has their servers specifically located in the US.

Any advice on how I can get around this to point to IPs specifically located in the US?

Comment: Did you try it? Some IP lookups say it's in Boston, USA, some say it's in UK. Maybe it gets routed depending on your location.

Comment: Try what? Sorry. When they resolve us.archive.ubuntu.com, it points to an IP in the UK. Other customers that are sort of child companies like them have mentioned theirs point to Amsterdam and other various locations outside of the US.

Comment: I mean the IP is `91.189.91.39`. And to this very same IP, different locations are reported from different services.

Comment: You could pick a US-based mirror ([list of mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)) directly instead of using the generic mirror domain names which might forward elsewhere. However, mirrors come and go, so that adds a tiny maintenance burden.

Comment: Thanks for this information, @user535733. This is actually very helpful. Any idea about security updates? (security.ubuntu.com)

Comment: That one will be a problem: security.ubuntu.com does not use mirrors, so you always get the latest patches from the source. Your customer's policy is counterproductive in this case, so requesting an exception to that policy seems appropriate. If Ubuntu is good enough for Netflix and Google to use on their production systems....